# html5+javascript visualizations: series of events popping up on a map with draggable timeline?

Tags: javascript, html, visualization, timeline

For a research project, I've collected 10M+ tweets and its location, I need to display them in a time series manner, with a timeline at the bottom, when dragging it, tweets would popping up showing its content and pinned to its location on a map.

Are there any prior art for this so I don't have to make it from scratch? I am in a bit hurry.

If I have to make it from scratch, what frameworks would be my best start? D3js+ReactJS with InfluxDB?